# Simple Javascript Slideshow Explination

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have found this script on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/austinkregel/pen/WvpGpZ) that has really peaked my interest, but it has me scratching my head as well. The entire code base isn't that large, in fact the whole slideshow script is only about 18 lines long. It's below,

```
(function(){
  var counter = 0, $items = document.querySelectorAll('.diy-slideshow section'),numItems = $items.length; 
  var showCurrent = function(){
    var itemToShow = Math.abs(counter%numItems);
    [].forEach.call( $items, function(el){
      el.classList.remove('show');
    });
    $items[itemToShow].classList.add('show');    
  };
  setInterval(function() {
     counter++;
     showCurrent();
  }, 5000);
})();
```

So the part I am confused about is the `showCurrent` function. More spesifically, it is the part that is

```
[].forEach.call($items, function(el){...};
```

Now I understand that `[]` would be an array but I don't understand where it gets the values for the array, how does the function know that there are X number of items in the array to loop through? What makes `[].forEach` loop through all of the known elements?

Comment: it gets the values from the first argument being passed to `.call()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[].foreach.call` is a shorthand for `Array.prototype.foreach.call`. Every javascript function is an object that has its own methods. [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is one of them.

The first argument of `call()` is `thisArg`, which represent the object that will behave as `this` during the function. In your example, `$items` (which is a `DOMElement` array) will be `this` in the `foreach` call.

Comment: Okay, I never knew they had a call method like that. Wouldn't the `[]` create a new array where `Array` would just be the accessor?

Comment: `[]` creates a new object, while `Array.prototype` refers to the class

Comment: So for the sake of speed (for minor thing) wouldn't it be better to use Array  compared to `[]`?

Comment: There is no need to worry that much about speed, but imo it should always be better to use `Array.prototype.foreach.call` instead of `[].foreach.call`, as it makes far more sense to me.